# How do I return an array after it has been swapped?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, return, parameter-passing

So I have my main method which is supposed to have an array of 1-20 print, and then I am supposed to pass that array in a loop for every even number occurrence. The `swap` method will switch the even number in the array with the next number... so in the array [1, 2, 3, 4, 5,..], 2 and 3 would switch and 4 and 5 would switch.

Here is the main method:

```
public class Lab_01_Tester {

public static void main (String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("Lab_01_nums.txt");
    int[] randArray  = Lab_01_ArrayUtilities.buildIntArray(20, 10, 29);

    String randArrayString = Arrays.toString(randArray);

    writer.write(randArrayString);
    System.out.print(randArrayString);

    writer.close();

    for (int i = 0; i < randArray.length - 1; i++)
    {
        if (randArray[i] % 2 == 0)
        {
            Lab_01_ArrayUtilities.swap (randArray, i, i + 1);
            i = i +1;
        }

        else;

    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print(randArrayString);

}

}
```

And here is the `swap` method that `randArray` is getting passed to:

```
public static int[] swap (int[] randArray, int i, int j)
{
    int temp = randArray[i];
    randArray[i] = randArray[j];
    randArray[j] = temp;

    return randArray;
}
```

My problem is that when the array is passed back, it is unchanged

Comment: Maybe like so, `randArray = Lab_01_ArrayUtilities.swap (randArray, i, i + 1);`?

Comment: Have you tested this carefully?  Just a quick read-through, but it looks like swap() should work.

Comment: Yeah, it's not necessary to return the array. The method will work regardless. Probably a problem with the other code, it looks bad with things like `else;`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't *need* to return anything (assuming you change the method signature to return `void`) - the elements of the array have been swapped in-place.

For example:

```
int[] array = { 3, 5, 4 };
swap(array, 0, 2);
System.out.println(array[0]); // 4
System.out.println(array[2]); // 3
```

This is your actual problem:

```
System.out.print(randArrayString);
```

You haven't changed `randArrayString` since you last printed it - so no wonder it's printing the same value. You just need to add this line again, just before printing it out:

```
randArrayString = Arrays.toString(randArray);
```

Comment: When I print my full array though nothing has changed.

Comment: @NikDesai: See my edit - you're not printing the current contents of the array... you're printing the same string you printed earlier.

Comment: oh wow.. Thank you so much, just saved me hours of swearing :)